# Compare multiple strings in XPath

Tags: xpath

Is there any better way to write things like `[node/text()="a" or node/text()="b"]` like this `[contains(arraytype("a", "b"), node/text())]`? Does the array type exist in XPath and can I use it inside the `contains` function to write more readable code?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Did you try `[node/text()=("a", "b")]`?

Comment: Require Xpath > 1 (dunno if it's 2 or 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code :

[image: note]**require xpath > 1**

```
saxon-lint --xpath '/students/student/name[text()=("A", "B")]' file.xml
```

### Output :

```
<name>A</name>
```

### Files :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
  <student>
    <stuId>1</stuId>
    <name>A</name>
    <mark>75</mark>
    <result></result>
  </student>
</students>
```

### Check

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) (my own project)

---

Thanks @Andersson for the tip